# Using the logarithm, find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, logarithms

> Using the logarithm find
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n}$$

Here is my attempt:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} n^{1/n}
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp(\ln(n^{1/n})) \\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp\Bigl(\frac{\ln(n)}{n}\Bigr) \\
&= \exp \Bigl(\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n}\Bigr)
\end{align}

Not sure if I can do this last step. And even if I can, not sure how to go further from here.

Comment: Check out the limit definition of a continuous function ;)

Comment: What's growing faster, numerator or denominator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last step is proper because exponentiation is continuous.  Use L'Hopital's Rule to evaluate the last limit.

Answer (score 3):

Without L'Hospital's rule:

Prove  that, for $x>1$, $\ln x<2\sqrt x$. Deduce the limit of $\frac{\ln x}x$ as $x$ tends to $+\infty$.

Comment: You meant as **x** tends ?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner: Yes, of course. Thanks for  pointing the typo!

Answer (score 3):

Using essentially nothing: Let $n^{1/n} = 1 +a_n.$ Think of $n$ large and apply the binomial theorem: $n = (1+a_n)^n = 1+na_n + [n(n-1)/2]a_n^2 + \dots$ Thus $n \ge [n(n-1)/2]a_n^2,$ which implies $1/[(n-1)/2] \ge a_n^2.$ This implies $a_n\to 0,$ hence $n^{1/n}\to 1.$

Comment: That is the way I would've presented (+1) despite defying the "Using the logarithm" preface.

Comment: @MarkViola Thanks. Right, I skipped the logarithm bit. My answer could be of use to some reader in the future. On the other hand, this question must have been asked lots of times on MSE.

Comment: I was saying that I would have been defiant also. ;-)  And you're probably right that this has been asked a number of times on MSE.